# as3 xml check if element exists

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I want to check if the element  in this structure exists for each child. The problem is that the children don't have the same name (product,prepack) and I don't want to change the order. Additionally I can't change the XML structure.

```
<items>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <prepack>
        <resourceImages />
    </prepack>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <prepack>
        <resourceImages />
    </prepack>
</items>
```

Comment: Which element ? Maybe an example of what you want to achieve will be better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
for each(var item : XML in xmlData.children())
{
    var hasImages : Boolean = (item.resourceImages.children().length() > 0);

    if(hasImages)
        trace("item has images")
}
```

Comment: I've changed the example. I need to run these checks in a for loop. Can you give an example?

Comment: What element do you want to check? Image?

Comment: yes I need to check in a for loop if the image element exists. But I don't know how to find the length()

Answer (score 10):

It appears there are two ways, but the check using undefined seems preferable.

```
if (item.image.length() > 0)
```

OR

```
if (item.image != undefined)
```

But beware, this always evaluates to true regardless if the node exists.

```
if (item.image)
```

Which is weird considering the undefined check.

Answer (score 6):

Depends also how is your first loop, but you can also check if the node is not `undefined` :

```
var xml:XML=<items>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <prepack>
        <resourceImages />
    </prepack>
    <product>
        <resourceImages>
            <image />
            <image />
        </resourceImages>
    </product>
    <prepack>
        <resourceImages />
    </prepack>
</items>;

//loop on all all resourceImage node
for each (var resourceImageXML:XML in xml..resourceImages){
    // and check if node if defined
    if (resourceImageXML.image != undefined) {
        // ok node have image
    }
}
```